# Is there a widget in flutter that allows you to create such a view?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I need to implement [such a widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwm8N.jpg) in Flutter. Full version of the page, where this widget is going to be used is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2n2m.jpg) Maybe you know build-in widgets, which could help me. But if there are none, what is the best way to implement this widget?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ListTile

```
ListTile(
  leading: const Text("Lbikgabsb"),
  trailing: Column( 
    children: [
       const Text("900 P"),
       const Text("2"), // add your decoration to the background 
    ),
   ],
 ),
),
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
SizedBox(
  height: your_height,
  width:double.infinity,
  child: Row(
    children:[
      Text("Lbikgabsb"),
      Column( 
        children: [
           const Text("900 P"),
           const Text("2"), // add your decoration to the background
    ],
  ),
),
```

You can choose whichever approach works best for your app